# How to bundle a React application and push it to Azure CDN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, azure, cdn

I have a React application and I want to reuse its compiled code into a dotnet MVC app. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- I want to build a bundle.js from the React application
- I want to publish that bundle.js into Azure CDN to be able to include this CDN in a web app and reuse the bundle.js

I am able to create the bundle. I just could not find any information about how to store that bundle into Azure CDN.

I was wondering if anyone did the same thing and could teach me how to do it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay first you need somewhere to host bundle.js.  CDN is designed to cache content as opposed to actually hosting it.

You have numerous hosting options.  You could include the bundle as part of your MVC app, as static content and have the CDN present your entire site, or you could use the Static Website and/or CDN features of an Azure Storage Account.  Just two options there.  See the following docs for more info on static website hosting:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website